# How to get the insert/update count from a merge statement in Snowflake-data?

Tags: c#, merge, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Would like to get the count of updates/inserts from the snowflake-data library in C#, but it's not clear to me that it's possible. Certainly my ODBC DB client allows it, but the `SnowflakeDbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync` returns an empty resultset. Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the `ExecuteReaderAsync` but does it ever return a resultset?  Since it at least looks like it's async execution, then it's not waiting for a return, right?  If that's the case, can you use the `ExecuteReader` instead?  Does it return a resultset?

From a Snowflake perspective, if you can capture the query_id via the driver, then you can leverage the `result_scan` function in Snowflake by either asking for the result of the last query, or specifying the exact query_id.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html

Answer (score 0):

Just execute your insert/update query with `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` method and it will return affected rows count. Source: [SnowflakeDbCommand](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/master/Snowflake.Data/Client/SnowflakeDbCommand.cs)